# ElasticSearch of MySQL for aggregating tens of millions of very simple records

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, bigdata

I'm wondering if **MySQL** or **ElasticSearch** is fundemantally the better tool to build this project?

Given a database of PING response times in the following format:

`Timestamp            Host       Success     ResponseTime
2020-02-01 12:00:00  1.1.1.1    1           5.00
2020-02-01 12:00:01  1.1.1.1    1           4.00
2020-02-01 12:00:01  8.8.8.8    1           2.00
2020-02-01 12:00:02  1.1.1.1    1           4.50
2020-02-01 12:00:02  8.8.8.8    1           1.80
2020-02-01 12:00:02  1.1.1.1    0           NULL`

I'd like to aggregate this data by 1-minute, 5-minute, 1-hour groups and harvesting min/max/average response times as well as counting the number of errors (success=0).

The goals are simple:

- fast read queries (don't worry about write speed)
- small storage space required
- possible to remove old records and regain used space
- preferably simple setup (not worrying about manually tuning the indexes, …)

Comment: What does the tag "bigdata" mean? what data load is expected, new docs/rows per sec? how many bytes per day? searches per second? desired response times? what is the retention time? do you need resilience/HA?

Comment: probably neither; why not just use a time-series db like druid?

Comment: @ibexit I expect tens of hosts and one ping per sec so let's say [50 hosts] x [24 * 3600 records per day] x [365 days] = 1.5B records.

Comment: @Backgammon I never heard about Druid, shame. How does it compare to Elasticsearch in terms of performance on 100Ms up to billions of records?

Comment: they have somewhat different strengths, but if you're using druid for true time-series data with minimal string/text processing, it far outperforms ES on analytics-type things like aggregations.

Comment: Hey @backgammon, do you have a source for the statement? Any benchmark or sth. else?

Answer (score 0):

I would use MySQL to build and incrementally augment one Summary table, broken down by 1-minute intervals.  It would also include min, max, count, sum.

I would hope that it would shrink down to one-tenth as many rows, thereby making queries run upwards of ten times as fast.

Once I am happy with all that, I would have the main table `PARTITION BY RANGE()` so that I could efficiently `DROP PARTITION` periodically.

Meanwhile, I would keep the summary table "forever".

I said `COUNT` and `SUM`, not `AVG`.  `AVG` can be derived from the (sum of sums) divided by (sum of counts).

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: Thanks, this is my currently architecture: MySQL table + another table by M1 breakdown with min/max/avg. I don't have the partition ready though, that's a good idea. No reason to bother with Elastic by your opinion?

Comment: @adamsfamily - Sorry, I don't know enough Elastic to address that part.

Comment: @adamsfamily - Based on your other comments, I would only save 1 day's data before summarizing.  That is, I would never have 1.5B rows of raw data, only 25M rows of summary data per year.  1.5B rows will be I/O-bound, regardless of what software is accessing it.  So, unless Elastic does some kind of auto-summarization, it cannot be as fast as what I suggest.

Comment: Please have a look at that elastic data frame feature: https://www.elastic.co/de/blog/elasticsearch-7-3-0-released